# Intellij highlighting not existing errors, thinking that LWJGL is not imported

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, lwjgl

I imported LWJGL to the libs folder inside the project. The application works fine, but Intellij is highlighting almost every line, thinking that lwjgl is not imported.
[image]

Is there any simple solution? I want to avoid importing the library another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invalidating caches via File → Invalidate caches/restart in the top menu.